# Make the materialize css design only effect a few elements

Tags: html, css, material-design

So, I really want to use some parts of the materialize css 
([Link to the css](http://materializecss.com/)) library, however I only want to use it on select elements on my site, such as a few buttons, maybe a menu item or two, however when you install it, it goes onto all the elements on the site it can, even if I have another css styling on it... which breaks most of my site's styling. Is there anyway to force it to ignore a styling? Even if I have to do something to all of the elements I want it to ignore, I know about using the !Important tag to force my design, but I don't want to have to overwrite every single css property. 
I hope there is a way, otherwise I might just not be able to use that library.

Comment: just copy what parts you want into your own css, html and javascript

Comment: So, remove all the other css code from the library I don't want to use?

Comment: I would say simply copy the parts that you want to keep, then testing on your page slowly